# Kafka Consumer Group Partition issue

Tags: apache-kafka

[image]

I read the Kafka wiki, have some problems about this picture.

1. For Consumer Group A, C1, C2, can only receive two partition message, like C1 only receive P0, C2 only receive P1?
2. As I know, one Consumer Group maps one Topic, so C1, C2 must have the same Topic, so PO, P1, P2, P3 has the same Topic, is that right?
3. So there's one contradiction, if problem 2 is right, then Consumer Group A and Consumer Group B has the same topic, so it's the contradiction about one Consumer Group maps one Topic.
4. How C1 control the P0, P1 message, if P0, P1 has the same topic, it means C1 will receive duplicate message, if not, how C1 control the different message with only one offset?
5. Question about "All partitions contains the same topic, at least that's how I interpret this picture".So I Suppose, the same topic named "test", then one producer produces the message "Hello test" for the this topic,  it means C1, C2, C3, C4 all will receive the same message?
   And for forth answer, C1 still receive the "Hello test" twice?
6. Can CG-A or CG-B receive the different topic message?
7. I didn't see any advantage about Consumer Group, "Sometimes the logic to read messages from Kafka doesn't care about handling the message offsets, it just wants the data. So the High Level Consumer is provided to abstract most of the details of consuming events from Kafka." from the Kafka's wiki,
   can you give me an example for the Consumer Group about this picture, like you seed CG-A is reporting tasking and CG-B is monitoring?
8. is it means P0, P1, P2, P3 from one topic named "test" will send different message? but I followed the Kafka's wiki, like:

   a. bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

   b. bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic test // partitions is 3

   c. bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

   d. bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning

   Then I type something in the producer, then consumer will show these message?

So how can these three partitions have different message?

9. Finally, How can I use command line to simulate this picture? Create Consume Group, then assign some consumer to it, then produce message, and can I monitor the mapping relationship between Partition and Consumer, and the message send from whihc partition?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In the picture, both Consumer Group A and Consumer Group B reads all 4 partitions. C1->[P0,P3], C2->[P1,P2]
   Let's imagine that there is a problem with C1 and this consumer terminates. Then C2 would take over the two remaining partitions and the mapping would become C2->[P0,P1,P2,P3]
   Let's imagine that you fix the problem, restart C1 and also add a third consumer C3 in the same group. Then you would have a mapping like C1->[P0], C2->[P1,P2], C3->[P3]
2. The concept of topics are somewhat separate from partitioning and could be a list of topics consumed by a consumer group but to give a simplify, the picture is likely meant to show only one topic being consumed by two independent consumer groups. We could imagine that CG-A is doing something simple to the messages and can manage this with only two instances while CG-B does more complex processing and require more parallelism. They could also have different time constraints so that CG-B might be more of a real-time consumer (e.g. direct monitoring) while CG-A might have less of a real-time constraint (e.g. reporting services). All partitions contain the same topic, at least that's how I interpret this picture.
3. No contradiction, Kafka is a multiple subscriber messaging system. You could have as many consumer groups consuming the same topic as you like, independently from each other.
4. A particular message exists only in one of the partitions so there won't be duplicate messages received. For redundancy purposes, Kafka has a replication feature as well but this is a different concept to partitions. Replication is not shown in the picture but that would mean that you would have something like [P0_leader,P1_follower,P2_follower,P3_leader] on Server 1 and [P0_follower,P1_leader,P2_leader,P3_follower] on Server 2.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. 
I still have question about "All partitions contains the same topic, at least that's how I interpret this picture".
So I Suppose, the same topic named "test", then one producer produces the message "Hello test" for the this topic, 
it means C1, C2, C3, C4 all will receive the same message?
And for forth answer, C1 still receive the "Hello test" twice? 
is something wrong, or I misunderstand something?

Comment: Thanks for your time again, these question worried me so long time, I started Kafka yesterday.

Comment: If you have a topic "test" and produce the message "Hello test" and don't use any specific message keying, then this message will end up in one of the partitions (plus optionally in replicas for that partition). If the message happens to end up in e.g. P1, then it can be consumed by C2 and C5. 

Lastly, how many times a consumer consumes a message is really up to that consumer but for the common case C1 would only receive the message once and then at specified intervals commit the message id of last consumed messages to Zookeeper as a kind of checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation. It seems i have much more things to learn about kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some test results on partition and consumer group id

```
Properties props = new Properties();
      //set all other properties as required
      props.put("group.id", "ConsumerGroup1");
      props.put("max.poll.records", "1");
      KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
```

consumer.group id is to load balance the produced data 
(**if the group.id is different for each consumer, each consumer will get the copy of data**)

if partition=1 and total consumers count = 2, only one out of two active consumer will get data

if partition=2 and total consumers count = 2, each of the two active consumers evenly get data

if partition=3 and total consumers count = 2, each of the two active consumers will get data. one consumer gets data from 2 partitions and other gets data from 1 partition.

if partition=3 and total consumers count = 3, each of the three active consumers evenly gets data.